# RSpec + FactoryGirl objects not recognizing private methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to TDD/build a Users API and I'm having a hard time with the `update` action particularly because of an `after_update` callback

**Model**

```
class User

  after_update :send_pro_user_updated_notification

  # ...

  private
  def send_pro_user_updated_notification
    # ...
  end
end
```

**Factory**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name { FFaker::Name.first_name }
    last_name { FFaker::Name.last_name }
    email { FFaker::Internet.email }
    password "12345678"
  end
end
```

**Spec**

```
describe "PUT #update" do
  context "when is successfully updated" do
    before :each do
      create(:user)
      put :update, { id: user.id, user: { first_name: 'Geoffrey' } }, format: :json
    end

    it "renders the json representation for the updated user" do
      expect(json_response[:data][:first_name]).to eq('Geoffrey')
    end

    it { should respond_with 200 }
  end
end
```

**Controller**

```
def update
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  if user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    # render json success response 
  else
    # render json error response 
  end
end
```

After running the test the error I get is the following:
`undefined local variable or method 'send_pro_user_updated_notification' for #<User:0x007f82b78e59e0>`

Even with `binding.pry` I try to call that method on the User object and get the same error, but I can call public methods.

If I remove the `after_update` callback the test passes.

Help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: While it doesn't address your main problem necessarily, I'll point out that you won't be able to access a private method from an object instance using `binding.pry`. You can't call a private method on an object, it can only be called internally. That being said, is there a place in your code that is trying to call that method on the object (`user.send_pro_user_updated_notification`) that you don't show us here?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. So 2 points:  

- I was calling it on binding.pry as `user.send(:send_pro_user_updated_notification)` and this was giving me the error mentioned above  

- So if you see the Model there is that `after_update :send_pro_user_updated_notification` which calls the private method everytime the user is updated

Comment: Hmm. And you're sure that it's not something like using the wrong version of your code to run a test? Like a different git branch that doesn't have the method defined?

Comment: Unfortunately yes I am sure, its funny because the test does not pass because of that reason but a call to the API actually works and updates the user

Comment: I've run into some funny issues before with the test environment not updating - like it is staying loaded and not taking into account all of my changes. It could be something like that. It's a shot in the dark, but that's all I've got left. Good luck!

Comment: Yea it probably is that because it really doesnt make much sense otherwise. Anyways man thanks for all your help and input